# Can someone explain the Application Pool and it Worker Process to me?

Tags: asp.net, iis, application-pool

I was reading [this](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/67e39bd8-317e-4cf6-b675-6431d4425248.mspx?mfr=true).

I understand that application pool:

1. Can seperate the process so one work process fail won't affect the
   other application in other application pool.
2. from the page above

> different application pools to isolate applications helps prevent one
>   customer from accessing, changing, or using confidential information
>   from another customers site.

But,

1. How the worker process will fail?  I only seen the situration that
   my asp.net application will throw an exception, but never seen a fail that will
   stop my whole worker process.  Can someone give me a real life
   example?
2. And how it can prevent one customer from accessing, changing
   confidentail from other customers site? If the confidentail
   information are stored into database, isn't that is not related?  Or
   do they refers to something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Worker processs can fail due to memory leakage and if there is unhandled/uncatched exception thrown by web application running in the process. Worker process automatically restarts after failure but all users in the system will be affected.
2. Same thing for security if different all web applications share same worker process, attacking ione and causing it to crash will cause everything to crash.

Comment: So, sometime if my application thrown an exeception (something like object is null) and routered to a stack trace page, at that point the Worker Process is already fail and started to restart?  When such fail happen, does it mean all the other users's session and global parameter(static) will be gone as well?

Comment: If you throw uncatched/unhandled exception, yes your worker process handling the application pool will restart, that will affect all applications served by that process. And yes all user's session variables will be gone and static parameters will reset to their initial values.

Comment: Now I know the impact for an exception is really big in same application pool lol  This maybe little off topic (Maybe I should open another question).  But then isn't is always the best to put every application in different pool?  Why could I want to assign into same pool?

Comment: @KingChan: Typically each application should have it's own pool.  However, there are times when sharing the same memory space is desired.  Also, to mitigate the hit to session in the event of a restart you can use out-of-process session storage.  Which, IMHO, negates 99% of the reason for using session in the first place.

Comment: @ChrisLively thanks for answering my question :) I didn't even know there is out-of-process session storage lol  Just done some reading, thanks everyone.